# django save file into folder

Tags: python, django

I want to save the file into separate folder but the folder name i will get it from the form that i dont know . but i have the working form now that will saved into user_ (something).

Can anybody tell me how to define the model class and views to get the folder name and the file which i upload saved automatically into the separate folder.

models.py

```
def content_file_name(instance, filename):
    return "user_{id}/{file}".format(id=instance, file=filename)

class Audio(models.Model):
    audiofile = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name)
```

views.py

```
def saved_file(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AudioForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newaudio = AudioForm()
            newaudio = Audio(audiofile = request.FILES['audiofile'])
            newaudio.save()

            #This is for redirect to the file save_list after post 
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app.views.saved_file'))
    else:
        form = AudioForm()

    # Load documents for the save_list page
    showfiles = Audio.objects.all()
    return render_to_response(
        'audio/file_upload.html',
        {'showfiles': showfiles, 'form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you make the folder name a part of your model and then modify the `content_file_name` function accordingly?

```
def content_file_name(instance, filename):
    return "user_{id}/{folder}/{file}".format(id=instance, folder=instance.folder_name, file=filename)

class Audio(models.Model):
    audiofile = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name)
    folder_name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

Comment: ok .. so model is ok now . but how to define form ? means tell me how to write view ..?

Comment: i given like this albumvalue = Album(audiofile = request.FILES['audiofile'])
            albumvalue = Album(albumname = request.POST.get('albumname', None)) .. Its throwing me an errorMultiValueDictKeyError "audiofile"

Comment: Your view and form should work as is. Just change the model as I suggested.

Comment: ok now i am getting into something .. when i given the folder name and file which i choose to upload and summit button gives error 'this field is required something' i dont know

Comment: Does your form have the new fields?

Comment: No extra fields . only name and select file is there why its asking previosly its not asking when i click it was saved into db but this time not

Comment: Then add the new field from your model in there. I'm assuming you have another HTML input field to get the folder name. You can map that input field to the new form field.

Comment: Please am very new . can you tell exactly. Currently i gave like {{ form }}

Comment: This is not working i gave like return "uploads/{folder}/{file}".format(id=instance, folder=instance.albumname, file=filename)

Comment: Its creating folder like uploads and the file upload is ther

Comment: the instance name not taking to create folder

Comment: You should have a form in forms.py. Can you tell us the contents?